# Can't copy chinese text from PDF

Tags: pdf, unicode, pdf-reader, chinese

I tried to open it with google docs, and tried the site i2orc to convert the file. But in both cases the Chinese characters are missing from the output, just as when i copy/paste them from the original file. Yes, i can copy them from the original file, but not totally. Some characters are ignored while selecting a Chinese phrase, while others are selected.

Link with the file in question : https://www.scribd.com/document/591991803/220826-HK-Gazette-34-Petitions-1

Hint : Search for the keyword '301', to find a good example of a chinese text

Can someone help me?

Comment: Wherever you are pasting to has to have the font to handle it.  Where are you pasting it ?

Comment: Both on google spreedsheet and google docs, on google worskpace

Comment: and i used a site that is suposed to converted the chinese text to microsoft word. So micrisift words as well, i guess

Comment: It's not so much that it doesn't copy - it won't even select… https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrdNV.png

Comment: Your link needs a sign-in to download...

Comment: @Tetsujin, i see, so your saying that, as it can't be selected at all ?Its in an image like format ? The only solutions is manually typing it ?

Comment: @harrymc, sorry about that, i couldn't find another fast upload site to share it

Comment: Vitor - I'm not really sure, but if you can't select it, you can't copy it. It has to be something to do with how the pdf was created. I've seen many pdfs [even in English] where the visual presentation doesn't match the underlying document data layout, making copy/paste a nightmare.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Understood. Thanks. I'll try to look up for some sort of scanner that uses a.i. to identify chinese characters from an image then. Maybe such a thing exists. Thanks

Comment: If it's a matter of PDF permissions, they can sometimes be removed.

Comment: @harrymc - how would perms allow the English to be selected, yet not the Chinese?

Comment: @Tetsujin: I need to see the PDF to comment further, but the poster has already solved his problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone ends up needing an answer someday :
Print the pdf text, crop it to increase the accurracy, and the use an online tool for chinese text extraction of image, like https://www.i2ocr.com/free-online-chinese-traditional-ocr.
I haven't tried it with large texts, but with small phrases works with accuracy. It's a long process, but at least works